# Unit for resources under Pod overview

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

This is under the Pod Overview of openshift 3.1.1.
What is the Unit of y axis for
RAM (what is B?), CPU Shares, and File System (Supposely MB?)?

[image: enter code here]
On the memory when I click on it, and when it goes to Prometheus, it shows as in the following:

[image]

Comment: "B" means "byte" and RAM is used the binary type unit as multiples of bytes, such as B, KiB, MiB and so on.

Comment: @DaeinPark in my case, it means 2 bytes of RAM? But that is not quite possible - I suspect the B should be GB? it makes more sense to me.

Comment: Usually, the size is too low to run any application as you mentioned, but the "B" unit means "byte" regardless of it.

Comment: @DaeinPark the size is too low to run any application as you mentioned - you mean the given memory size is not accurate?

Comment: I don't know whether the memory metrics is not correct or not. I mean the size is low usually, but the graph just is shown the value as it is collected. As I remember, the memory usage depends on heapster component of the kubelet on the host which is scheduled the running pod. You may need the real usage from the host.

Comment: I think you need to ask how to check the memory real usage of the pod for comparison with the web console graph usage using other ticket.

Comment: @DaeinPark I think it should be GB, I updated the question with graph in Prometheus - I get to there when I click on the memory graph (show with unit B) in pod overview.

Comment: @william007 is right, the `B` means billion, hence `GB`.